# I'm working on a php shopping list function/api

Tags: php, json, oracle, api

return an array of Shopping List objects, either for a shopper, or the lists that have the “suggested” flag = ‘Y’

when i manually add the token to the $_GET i come back with a blank array.  `[{},{}]`
but if i var_dump($shopper_list) i get two different users list.. it should only be one since one login should equal one token:

```
[{},{}]
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(UserShoppingList)#4 (14) {
    ["sign_in_token":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["Shopper":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["ID":protected]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["SHOPPING_LIST_NAME":protected]=>
    string(18) "kj's shopping list"
    ["SUGGESTION":protected]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["SEQUENCE":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["ShoppingListItem":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["api_url":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["table":"Base":private]=>
    string(23) "jfw_shopping_list_names"
    ["procedure":"Base":private]=>
    NULL
    ["procedure_args":"Base":private]=>
    NULL
    ["keys":"Base":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["ID"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["alias_db_to_php":"Base":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["alias_php_to_db":"Base":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(UserShoppingList)#5 (14) {
    ["sign_in_token":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["Shopper":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["ID":protected]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["SHOPPING_LIST_NAME":protected]=>
    string(20) "bonner shopping list"
    ["SUGGESTION":protected]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["SEQUENCE":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["ShoppingListItem":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["api_url":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["table":"Base":private]=>
    string(23) "jfw_shopping_list_names"
    ["procedure":"Base":private]=>
    NULL
    ["procedure_args":"Base":private]=>
    NULL
    ["keys":"Base":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["ID"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["alias_db_to_php":"Base":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["alias_php_to_db":"Base":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

My php page (get_shopping_lists.php) looks like so:

```
/*
    This script is used to return a JSON array of ShoppingList objects.
    Those objects can be limited to either only "suggested" ShoppingList names,
    or to all of the lists for a single Shopper.  So, either the shopper_id or
    the boolean "suggested_only" should be set.
*/
if(!isset($_GET['token']) && !isset($_GET['suggested_only'])) {
    die('Must pass-in either a \'token\' or \'suggested_only\' flag');
}

if(isset($_GET['token'])) {
    $shopper = new Shopper($_GET['token'])
    or die('Could not instantiate a new Shopper from the \'token\' passed-in');

    $shopper_lists = $shopper->get_lists(true);
    echo json_encode($shopper_lists);
}

if(isset($_GET['suggested_only']) && $_GET['suggested_only'] == 'true') {

}
```

I'm looking to return an array of Shopping List objects, either for a shopper (where you’d pass-in a token to the “get_lists” function of the Shopper class), or the lists that have the “suggested” flag = ‘Y’ if you were to pass another parameter through to signify that you only want the suggested lists.  Each of those options would call the pieces in the framework differently.

Shopper Class:

```
// Most objects in this framework are populated by calling the constructor, but
// this one has a variety of entry points. They don't do any sanity checking
// with eachother, so you can have $user->create and $user->register refer to
// completely different rows.
class Shopper extends Base {

    protected $shopper_id;
    protected $email;
    protected $user_name;
    protected $temp_token;
    protected $sign_in_token;

    protected $UserShoppingList;

    function __construct($email = null) {
        // For testing use only. Declined to wrap in this_is_dev because I
        // foresee using it somewhere in the code, pushing live, and being 
//        parent::__construct('jfw_shoppers', array('SHOPPER_ID' => $shopper_id));

        // Allow them to pass an e-mail address or the token
        if (strpos($email, '@') === false) {
            $this->sign_in_token = $email;
        } else {
            $this->email = $email;
        }
    }

    // todo: need a new function to do the actual activation.
    public function activate($temp_token) {
        global $db;

        $this->set_temp_token($temp_token);

        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':i_temp_token', $this->get_temp_token());

        // Returns a Y or N
        return $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.Activate_User(:i_temp_token)', $vars) == 'Y';
    }

    public function create($password) {
        global $db;

        if (!$this->get_email() || !$this->get_username()) {
            return false;
        }

        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':email', $this->get_email());
        $vars[] = array(':username', $this->get_username());
        $vars[] = array(':password', $password);

        $id = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.create_user(:email, :username,  :password)', $vars);
        $this->set_id($id);

        // If it failed, it'll puke on the procedure. If we've come this far, we
        // know it worked.
        return true;
    }

    public function get_email() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    private function get_id() {
        if (isset($this->shopper_id)) {
            return $this->shopper_id;

        // If this object has an e-mail address or the user sent one
        } else if ($this->get_email())  {
            global $db;

            $vars = array();
            $vars[] = array(':i_email_id', $this->get_email());

            // FUNCTION get_id_by_email(i_email_id IN jfw_shoppers.email%TYPE)
            $id = array_pop(array_pop($db->get_function('custom.japi_shopper_identity.get_id_by_email(:i_email_id)', $vars)));

            $this->set_id($id);
            $this->shopper_id = $id;
            return $this->shopper_id;

        // Can also get from token
        } else if ($this->get_sign_in_token())  {
            // todo: call get_id_by_token
            return false;
        }
    }


    // todo: test
    public function get_lists($clobber = false) {
        global $pd;
//        $pd->print_object($this, 'User - has token?');
//        $pd->print_object($this->get_sign_in_token(), 'Token');

        if ($this->UserShoppingList != null && !$clobber) {
            return $this->UserShoppingList;

        } else if ($this->get_sign_in_token()) {
            global $db;
            $pd->print_object($this, 'User - has token?');
            $pd->print_object(strtolower($this->get_sign_in_token()), 'token?');

            $vars = array();
            $vars[] = array(':i_sign_in_token', strtolower($this->get_sign_in_token()));

            $pd->print_object($this->get_sign_in_token(), 'About to seek lists using token');
            $rows = $db->get_function('custom.japi_shopper_identity.get_lists_for_shopper(:i_sign_in_token)', $vars);
            $pd->print_object($rows, 'Rows returned by get_lists using token '.$this->get_sign_in_token());

            // Turn the rows into objects
            $this->UserShoppingList = array_to_objects($rows, 'UserShoppingList');

            return $this->UserShoppingList;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function get_sign_in_token() {
        if ($this->sign_in_token != null) {
            return $this->sign_in_token;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function get_temp_token() {
        if ($this->temp_token != null) {
            return $this->temp_token;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function get_username() {
        return $this->user_name;
    }

    public function json($obj = null, $return_json = false) {
        if ($obj == null) {
            $obj = $this;
        }
        return parent::json($obj, $return_json);
    }

    // Most objects in this framework are populated by calling the constructor,
    // but the only way to populate this one is to call this function with good 
    // credentials.
    public function login($password) {
        global $db;

        if (!$this->get_email()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Log them in now that we know who they are. 
        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':i_email_id', $this->get_email());
        $vars[] = array(':i_password', $password);

        // This also exists, but is not yet in use:
        // $token = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.login_by_username(:i_username, :i_password)', $vars);
        $token = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.Login_by_Email(:i_email_id, :i_password)', $vars);
        // todo: what if it's bad credentials?

        if ($token == null) {
            return false;

        } else {
            $this->set_sign_in_token($token);
            return $this->get_sign_in_token();
        }
    }

    public function password_reset($tmp_token, $password) {
        global $db;

        if (strlen($password) < 8) {
            return false;
        }

        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':temp_token', $tmp_token);
        $vars[] = array(':new_password', $password);

        return $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.password_reset(:temp_token, :new_password)', $vars) == 'Y';
    }

    public function request_activation() {
        global $db;

        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':i_shopper_id', $this->get_id());

        // Returns a temp token
        $temp_token = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.activate_user_request(:i_shopper_id)', $vars);

        if ($temp_token == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->send_activation_email();
            return $temp_token;
        }
    }

    public function request_password_reset() {
        global $db, $pd;

        if (!$this->get_id()) {
            return false;
        }

        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':shopper_id', $this->get_id());

        $temp_token = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.password_reset_request(:shopper_id)', $vars);
        if ($temp_token == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->set_temp_token($temp_token);
            $pd->print_object('About to send the e-mail');
            $this->send_password_email();
            $pd->print_object('Sent the email');
            return $this->get_temp_token();
        }
    }


    private function send_activation_email() {
        if (!$this->get_email() || !$this->get_temp_token())  {
            return false;
        }


        $fancy = '
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="logo.jpg" /></div>
<h2>Welcome to com!</h2>
<p>To complete your registration, <a href="todo: ">click here</a> or copy and paste the URL into your browser:</p>

URL?token='.$this->get_temp_token().'

Thanks!
';

        $plain = 'Welcome to com!

To complete your registration, please activate your account by going to the URL below:

URL?token='.$this->get_temp_token().'

Thanks!
';

        // todo: subject could probably be better
        return email_customer($this->get_email(), 'Welcome to com!', $fancy, $plain);
    }


    private function send_password_email() {
        global $pd;
        $pd->print_object('In send_password_email');
        $pd->print_object($this->get_email(), 'E-mail');
        $pd->print_object($this->get_temp_token(), 'Token');

        if (!$this->get_email() || !$this->get_temp_token())  {
            return false;
        }

        $pd->print_object($this->get_email(), 'Have all the data I need');


        $fancy = '
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="logo.jpg" /></div>
<h2>Welcome to com!</h2>
<p>To reset your password, <a href="todo: ">click here</a> or copy and paste the URL into your browser:</p>

<p>URL?token='.$this->get_temp_token().'</p>

<p>Thanks!</p>
';
        $plain = 'Welcome to com!

To reset your password by going to the URL below:

URL?token='.$this->get_temp_token().'

Thanks!
';
        $pd->print_object('About to actually e-mail');


        return email_customer($this->get_email(), "Reset your com password", $fancy, $plain);
    }

    public function set_email($email) {
        return $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function set_id($email) {
        return $this->shopper_id;
    }

    public function set_sign_in_token($token) {
        return $this->sign_in_token = $token;
    }

    public function set_temp_token($token) {
        return $this->temp_token = $token;
    }

    public function set_username($username) {
        return $this->user_name = $username;
    }
}
```

I'm a bit perplexed atm on how to reference the shoppers list and if they don't have a list than to select the suggested.

I got some test lists in my (oracle11g) DB:

```
     ID SHOPPING_LIST_NAME                                 S SEQUENCE
------- -------------------------------------------------- - --------
      3 793d7384fa4fa247d6fae07db104147d0a2dad6e           N
      1 test amnaik shopping list                          N
      4 kj's shopping list                                 N
      5 kj's shopping list from 1384201636                 N
      6 kj's shopping list from 1384201659                 N
      7 kj's shopping list from 1384202055                 N
      8 kj's shopping list from 1384202089                 N
      2 bonner shopping list                               N

8 rows selected.



SHOPPING_LIST_ID SHOPPER_ID ITM_CD    QUANTITY CHANGE_DA CHANGE_US A O
---------------- ---------- --------- -------- --------- --------- - -
               1          2 ABI85MT06        4 28-OCT-13 CUSTOM    N N
               1          1 STZ28AC1         3 11-NOV-13 CUSTOM    Y N
               1          1 ABI85MT06        3 11-NOV-13 CUSTOM    Y N
               1          1 XYZ              1                     Y N
               2          1 XYZ              1                     Y N
               4         67 MND44SA01        1                     Y N
               4         67 MND44SA02        1                     Y N
               2         67 MND44SA02        1                     Y N
               1          1 ABCDEF           1                     Y N

9 rows selected.
```

As usual, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full code of the Shopper class? It's not clear once you instantiate that class with a token how their list is populated. Based on the code above, you create a new Shopper object and then call get_lists() which just grabs what is already in UserShoppingList. You'll either need to load this in the classes construct or get_lists() should actually fetch this from the db

Comment: Thanks @ChrisRasco i posted the whole Shopper class now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on that Shopper class, your updated get_lists function is calling a db method:

```
$rows = $db->get_function('custom.japi_shopper_identity.get_lists_for_shopper(:i_sign_in_token)', $vars);
```

This method returns an array that I have to assume is the query results from the oracle db. After you convert it to a set of objects and return it back to get_shopping_lists.php, you need to check to ensure this value isn't false, since that's your final else condition in the get_lists() method call. If it is, output some type of error message (probably in JSON format if that's what your consumer is expecting).

As for the new things you want to add

- auto-create a list if they don't have one and
- get suggested lists

For the first one, after you fetch the rows you'll check to ensure $rows isn't empty and then call a method to create a list (presumably also some type of customer.japi_shopper... function on the oracle side.

For the second, you'll branch the logic with an if/else (if $suggested == true, fetch those results; else, do what you are already doing...)

Comment: Thanks for responding but I'm still a bit confused Chris.

Comment: Should i be building these other two functions in the shopper class or just add them to my get_shopping_lists.php page?

Comment: Right now i keep getting the die message... "Must pass-in either a 'token' or 'suggested_only' flag"

Comment: Drop me an email and we can discuss that way or I can jump on IRC. Email is in my profile.

Comment: Email sent. Thanks for sticking in there with me.

Comment: I put up a bounty on this guy.